# Scraping Nodescreenshots In Python using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

My friends and I play a card game and want to programm a custom website, so we can play eventhough we can't meet. The cards of the game are all accessible through the games website. They are stored at specific locations like this:

game/card-database/filters/upgrade-details/**id**.

The programm is supposed to iterate through all ids and to take the equivalent of a "Nodescreenshot" in the chrome inspector

My try was the following:

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)


for i in range(2000):
    driver.get(f"https://squadbuilder.fantasyflightgames.com/card-database/filters/upgrade-details/{i}")
    time.sleep(5)
    card_div = driver.find_element_by_class("sc-fzpans sc-fzplWN sc-fzoLag sc-pjSSY joSaYB")
    location = card_div.location
    size = card_div.size
    png = driver.get_screenshot_as_png()  # saves screenshot of entire page

    im = Image.open(BytesIO(png))  # uses PIL library to open image in memory

    left = location['x']
    top = location['y']
    right = location['x'] + size['width']
    bottom = location['y'] + size['height']

    im = im.crop((left, top, right, bottom))  # defines crop points
    im.save(f'Card{i}.png')  # saves new cropped image
driver.close()
```

But the code always runs into an error, where it can't find the div

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It's mostly due to using headless with some sites. What I'd suggest is adding user-agents and printing out the driver.page_source. Also finding by class name takes in a singular value and not multiple use css selector instead. You'd also run into issues screenshotting in headless as well.

Comment: Thanks Arundeep Chohan, the programm is working without an problem, you really made my day!